# How to setup vault on an external server

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault

I have been able to use vault on local host with the following .hcl file.

```
backend "consul" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
  path = "vault"
}

listener "tcp" {
 address = "127.0.0.1:8200"
 tls_disable = 1
}
```

I want to install vault on a box in the cloud and my team needs to query and use vault individually. Any tips on how I can do this?

Should I redirect all traffic from port 80 to the localhost on the box to use the API?

Using the following library https://github.com/ianunruh/hvac

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No reason why you wouldn't just leave vault running on port 8200 and access remotely on that port. I'd certainly set up TLS though - that's easy enough:

```
listener "tcp" {
  address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 0
  tls_cert_file = "/etc/vault.crt"
  tls_key_file = "/etc/vault.key"
  tls_min_version = "tls12"
}
```

You'll need a valid certificate. One of my use cases for vault is to be a certificate authority, so I'm using a cert which was generated by vault itself. Otherwise you'd get one from the usual locations.

Comment: client = hvac.Client(url='http://10.240.0.4:8200')
print(client.is_initialized()) 

The test above gives me a connection timeout error. Any ideas?    
     
Log Level: info
Mlock: supported: true, enabled: false
Backend: consul (HA available)
Advertise Address: http://10.240.0.4:8200
Listener 1: tcp (addr: "0.0.0.0:8200", tls: "disabled")
Version: Vault v0.5.0

Thank you

Comment: Is there a firewall blocking it? Can you telnet to 10.200.0.4 8200?

Comment: Yes that was the issue. Thank you.